# Local storage data not saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

**UPDATE: its working. problem was from useEffect**

When I try to 'submit' a specific task, it is shown in the local storage that the status attribute is not changed. I wonder where I am going wrong. The data i am trying to use to update the local storage is initialState.stuff .

Here is my code for reducer.js:

```
const reducer = (state,action)=>{
    if(action.type ==="completed"){
//the relevant attributes to be changed 

        let temp = state.stuff.map((task)=>{
            if(task.id === action.payload){
                return {...task,status:status,enddate:enddate}
            }
            return task;
        });
// the rest of the parts of this code is irrelevant
```

here is my code for context.js:

```
import React, {useState,useContext,useEffect,useReducer} from "react"
import reducer from "./reducer";
const AppContext = React.createContext()

const initialState = {
    stuff: null
}
const AppProvider =  ({children}) =>{
    const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([])
    const [status,changeStatus] = useState("");
    const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
    const complete = (id) =>{
        dispatch({type:"completed",payload:id})
        console.log("done", initialState.stuff)
        setTasks(initialState.stuff)
    }

    const deleted = (id) =>{
        dispatch({type:"deleted",payload:id})
    }

    const getLocalStorage = () =>{
        state.stuff = localStorage.getItem("tasks")
        if(state.stuff){
          state.stuff = JSON.parse(state.stuff)
          return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
        }
        else{
          return []
        }
      }
      const fetchData = async()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        setTasks(getLocalStorage());
        setLoading(false);
      }
      useEffect(()=>{
          fetchData()
      },[])

      useEffect(()=>{
        localStorage.setItem("tasks",JSON.stringify(tasks))
      },[tasks])


return <AppContext.Provider
value = {{
    loading,
    tasks,setTasks
}}>
    {children}
</AppContext.Provider>
}


export const useGlobalContext = () =>{
    return useContext(AppContext)
}
export {AppContext,AppProvider}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the state at "state.stuff = localStorage.getItem..." in getLocalStorage? Cause it doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: err yes @Zeeshan

Comment: im actually trying to update the state and then update the local storage

Answer (score 0):

I think there **might be** (I have not read your code completely) variable collision in your code. You can try writing `window.localStorage` instead of `localStorage` and check whether it solves your problem.